# why won't my jbutton with image show up with graphics java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I'm having trouble with my jbutton not displaying. If i do not use paintComponent, then my JButtons with images show up no problem. However now, the image does not show up. If i hover over where it should be, the image shows up for one second. So it's like the button is still there, just maybe below the background?

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    //layout variables
    private ImageIcon right,left,up,down;
    private JButton rightButton,leftButton,upButton,downButton;

    //play variables
    private boolean play=false;
    private int score=0;

    private int paddleX= 200; //paddle X position
    private int paddleY= 300; //paddle Y pos
    private int ballX= 210; //ball x position
    private int ballY= 260; //ball y position
    private int ballXdir=-1; //x direction
    private int ballYdir=-2; //y direction

    private Timer time; //my timer

    public Game() {
        Display(); //display the layout
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        time= new Timer(8,this);
        time.start();
    }

    public void Display(){

        //setLayout
        this.setLayout(null);

        //Setting the Images
        //right = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images\\rightIcon.png"));
        left = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images\\leftIcon.png"));
        up = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images\\upIcon.png"));
        down = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images\\downIcon.png"));

        //Setting the JButtons for the arrow images
        rightButton= new JButton("right");
        rightButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(paddleX>=400){
                    paddleX=400;
                }
                else{
                    moveRight();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        //rightButton.setOpaque(false);
        //rightButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        //rightButton.setBorderPainted(false);

        leftButton= new JButton(left);
        leftButton.setOpaque(false);
        leftButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        leftButton.setBorderPainted(false);

        upButton= new JButton(up);
        upButton.setOpaque(false);
        upButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        upButton.setBorderPainted(false);

        downButton= new JButton(down);
        downButton.setOpaque(false);
        downButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        downButton.setBorderPainted(false);

        //setting image bounds and adding it to screen
        rightButton.setBounds(135,450,50,50);
        leftButton.setBounds(45,450,50,50);
        upButton.setBounds(90,400,50,50);
        downButton.setBounds(90,500,50,50);

        //rightButton.addActionListener(this);
        leftButton.addActionListener(this);

        add(upButton);
        add(downButton);
        add(leftButton);
        add(rightButton);



    }

    //painting the screen with graphics
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(25,25,425,300); //game area

        //drawing the paddle
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(paddleX,paddleY,50,8);

        //drawing the ball
        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
        g.fillOval(ballX,ballY,20,20);

        g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        time.start();

        if(e.getSource()==right) {
            if(paddleX>=400){
                paddleX=400;
            }
            else{
                moveRight();
            }           
        }

        if(e.getSource()==left) {
            if(paddleX<35){
                paddleX=35;
            }
            else{
                moveLeft();
            }
        }

        repaint();

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            if(paddleX>=400){
                paddleX=400;
            }
            else{
                moveRight();
            }

        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            if(paddleX<35){
                paddleX=35;
            }
            else{
                moveLeft();
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    public void moveRight(){
        play=true;
        paddleX+=10;
    }

    public void moveLeft(){
        play=true;
        paddleX-=10;
    }


}
```

Comment: Well, `g.dispose();` is an immediate issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) as it will explain how the painting system works.

Basically, you are passed a reference to the `Graphics` context which is currently been used to perform the current paint pass, via the `paintComponent` method.  This is a shared resource.  All components involved in the paint pass are passed the same `Graphics` context.

By calling `dispose`, you are releasing all the underlying resources for the context, which can, on some systems, prevent other components from been painted.

> But they paint when I move my mouse over them

Because components can be painted independently of their parent, but you also call `repaint` on the parent component, which will, you guessed it, paint it's children.

## Recommendations

- Create a custom component dedicated solely to performing the custom painting operations (and possible some of the other basic game functions)
- Create another component to hold the buttons (and make use of appropriate layouts)
- Use a some kind of data model which is shared between them.  This model will hold the state of the "actions" (ie up/down/left/right) and the "engine" will use this information to update the state of the game.
- Make use of the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will solve the unreliability issues associated with `KeyListener`